# E4 check if part is opened in another perspective

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

In E4 you can check if a part is visible using `EPartService.isPartVisible(MPart part)`. However I would like to check if a part is visible/opened in another perspective WITHOUT changing the current perspective. I am doing this check many times so switching between active/other perspective every time would not be optimal. Is this doable ?

Comment: `EPartService.isPartOrPlaceholderInPerspective` looks like it does that.

Comment: yes it seem to work fine. don't know how I missed that. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `EPartService.isPartOrPlaceholderInPerspective` method does this.

```java
public boolean isPartOrPlaceholderInPerspective(String elementId, MPerspective perspective)
```

This looks for the specified id in the given perspective and checks that the `isVisible` and `isToBeRendered` flags are true.